# How to migrate MongoDB to GCP?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I am working on a project that needs to move MongoDB to GCP. I am new to MongoDB and GCP!

What is the best way to achieve this?

This is what I need to accomplished:

1. Create MongoDB instance in GCP
2. Migrate/Clone MongoDB to GCP

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want/need to use MongoDB on Google cloud or do you want/can change the database engine? That's the first question. Then, if you use MongoDB, use MongoDB atlas solution for a serverless/managed mongoDB solution

Comment: Yes I have to use MongoDB on Google Cloud. Okay great MongoDB Atlas. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Options:**

1. mongoDB SaaS(ATLAS) for small deployments cheap , for bigger deployments become expensive. Best option for enterprise production deployments!
2. Manual deployment on GCE VMs , the easy and most customizable and cheap option. Requiere additional effort for monitoring , backup etc.
3. K8s automated via mongoDB enteprise operator -> require license -> expensive but modern.
4. K8s automated via 3th party custom helm chart , require some effort but also cheap.
5. Alternative cloud options they have all pros and cons ...